# Grails Spring Security Facebook Plugin not Working

Tags: facebook, spring, spring-mvc, grails

I am trying to use spring security facebook plugin in grails. Here is my configuaration

BuildConfig.groovy:

```
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC2"
compile ":spring-security-facebook:0.15.2-CORE2"
```

Config.groovy:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.facebook.domain.classname='com.spring.grails.loginapp.domains.auth.FacebookUser'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.facebook.appId='711430758877160'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.facebook.secret= *****
grails.plugins.springsecurity.facebook.autoCreate.enabled=true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.facebook.autoCreate.roles=['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_FACEBOOK']
```

I created domin using s2-init-facebook. I created Login with facebook in my GSP.

But When I try to click Login With Facebook, I got Invalid app id error.

Invalid App ID: Invalid

When I go to http://graph.facebook.com/645351175512630 to verify my App it seems to be correct.

I Followed documentation of grails spring security facebook plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to put configuration into `Config.groovy`. `BuildConfig` is used for dependencies.

Second, as you're using Spring Security Core version **2.x**, then correct config prefix is `grails.plugin.springsecurity` (not `grails.plugins.springsecurity`, without `s`)

Comment: But Again to got redirect problem. Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains. I set domain to localhost in my app.

Comment: make sure that it matches (including port). And i'm not sure that it does work with `localhost`

Comment: Including port in domain is not allowed there.

Comment: ?? allowed. Website URL could be any valid URL

Comment: no, I tried to place, localhost:8080 in domain that is not allowed. In website url I placed http://localhost:808/spring-login which is my app url, But it didn't work